# React Native Animated. You must specify exactly one property per transform object

Tags: react-native

I get this error trying to translate a View using `translateX` and `translateY`

> ExceptionsManager.js:173 JSON value '(
>           {
>           translateX = 0;
>           translateY = 120;
>       } )' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to a CATransform3D. You must specify exactly one property per transform
>   object.

Here is my component:

```
  const BounceInUp: FC<IAnimatedView> = ({ children, teddyBear }) => {
  const bounceValue = new Animated.Value(120);
  const shakeValue = new Animated.Value(0);

  const animate = useCallback(() => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.delay(300),
      Animated.spring(bounceValue, {
        useNativeDriver: true,
        toValue: -10,
        velocity: 3,
        friction: 8,
      }),
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(shakeValue, { toValue: 10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
        Animated.timing(shakeValue, { toValue: -10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
        Animated.timing(shakeValue, { toValue: 10, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
        Animated.timing(shakeValue, { toValue: 0, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true }),
      ]),
    ]).start();
  }, [bounceValue, shakeValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    animate();
  }, [teddyBear.id]);

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.subView, { transform: [{ translateY: bounceValue, translateX: shakeValue }] }]}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

How can I apply one animation on X and Y without getting this error?

Comment: try to put `translateX` and `translateY` each in an object `transform: [{ translateY: bounceValue }, { translateX: shakeValue }]`

Comment: ah thanks. That works well I think.

Comment: @MahdiN I'll upvote if you answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const bounceValue = new Animated.Value(120);` I think you might want to try initialising value like this: `const valueXY = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 120 });` because you want to animate value x and y.

Then:

```
Animated.spring(valueXY, {
        useNativeDriver: true,
        toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        velocity: 3,
        friction: 8,
      }),
```

and in your sequence:

`Animated.timing(valueXY, { toValue: { x: 10, y: 0 }, duration: 100, useNativeDriver: true })`

Also in style `<Animated.View style={[styles.subView, { transform: valueXY.getTranslateTransform() }]}>`

You can check here for more info https://animationbook.codedaily.io/animated-value-xy/

Answer (score 31):

You should put each transformation (`translateX` and `translateY`) in an object inside trasform array.

```
transform: [{ translateY: bounceValue }, { translateX: shakeValue }]
```